# Give full permission to files inside a shared folder in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing

I want to share a folder on my Windows XP PC and let everyone read or write or delete the files in shared folder. However when I use another Windows 7 PC access the folder and want to copy or cut the files inside, "File Access Denied" occurs.

I have added "Everyone" to group in security tab of the shared folder and give full control to it. But still, when I check the security tab of the files inside the shared folder, there is no "Everyone" inside the group.

What I can do is only add "Everyone" to all the files every time.
How to solve this?

Comment: This is easily done with domain accounts.  More information about the network configuration is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to keep in mind when your PC says "Everyone", that means everyone the PC is aware of. Each user has a unique SID. The SID is generated by each PC (or DC on a domain). So "everyone" is the list of SID's your pc know about. As Ramhound mentioned this would easily be solved with a domain because all users are stored and shared amongst all the PCs on the domain. A better bet may be mapping the share folder, but using alternate credentials. The credentials will match ones from the share machine. Be sure to use the shared folders IP as the domain prefix in the username e.g. `192.168.1.10\administrator`